# two Ubuntu 12.04, 1x Netgear router

Tags: squid, reverse-proxy, ubuntu-12.04

Ok, so I have 192.168.x.14 with port 80 open and I have set the netgear router to point there
then I have 192.168.x.12 with apache running but when I try to connect using chrome to the website hosted on .12 it cant find it, how do I set up .14 to also check .12

```
/nagios is running on .12
while
/munin is running on .14
```

Thank you for helping

I know about Squid, but I don't know what to do? Do I use that or something else.

Comment: was able to get it to work I'll post the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have two web servers behind the NAT. Because of how port forwarding is designed you can port redirect to only one of them.

To make your life easier just use a different port for the other server and that should solve your problems. I mean you can still use complex proxy solutions like varnish, HAproxy, squid, mod_proxy from apache, etc but there is no point for the setup you need.

Comment: I understand I can do that, but say I want to go to www.example.com I want my server to know go to .12 instead of .14 - I call it learning lol :)

Comment: Aha than as I said you can use for example mod_proxy if you already have your apache installed and redirect some of the request to the other web server. Check at the documentation online.

Answer (score -1):

http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Apache2_reverse_proxies - this is how I solved it, follow that if you have to do what I needed.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.